# Running passenger_native_support.so on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, passenger

When I deploy my Rails 3 app with Passenger 5.3.1 on heroku I see the following failed downloads in the logs

> Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.3.1/rubyext-ruby-2.2.7-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
>
> Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.3.1/rubyext-ruby-2.2.7-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden

Can someone advise how I can get around this? I checked said URLs and the files are at a different URL (the path my app tries to download from is slightly wrong).
Can I configure the download URL somewhere?

Due to lack of SSH access on heroku I am not quite sure where to go from here.

I'm also not sure about the advantages of PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable
and where I would configure this when deploying to heroku.

Logs:

> 2018-05-22T14:22:02.337983+00:00 app[web.1]: --> Downloading a Phusion Passenger agent binary for your platform
>   2018-05-22T14:22:02.709603+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2018-05-22T14:22:02.709640+00:00 app[web.1]: --> Installing Nginx 1.14.0 engine
>   2018-05-22T14:22:02.779900+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2018-05-22T14:22:02.779946+00:00 app[web.1]: --------------------------
>   2018-05-22T14:22:02.779967+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2018-05-22T14:22:02.792581+00:00 app[web.1]: [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (u56245) and Ruby interpreter...
>   2018-05-22T14:22:02.792586+00:00 app[web.1]: (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
>   2018-05-22T14:22:03.114593+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file:
>   2018-05-22T14:22:03.114653+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/passenger_native_support-fgpk65.log
>   2018-05-22T14:22:03.114732+00:00 app[web.1]: [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
>   2018-05-22T14:22:03.114766+00:00 app[web.1]: (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
>   2018-05-22T14:22:03.837288+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.3.1/rubyext-ruby-2.2.7-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
>   2018-05-22T14:22:03.837312+00:00 app[web.1]: Trying next mirror...
>   2018-05-22T14:22:04.331785+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.3.1/rubyext-ruby-2.2.7-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
>   2018-05-22T14:22:04.332030+00:00 app[web.1]: [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download)
>   2018-05-22T14:22:04.332036+00:00 app[web.1]: --> Passenger will still operate normally.
>   2018-05-22T14:22:04.410350+00:00 app[web.1]: =============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
>   2018-05-22T14:22:04.410358+00:00 app[web.1]: PID file: /app/passenger.11176.pid
>   2018-05-22T14:22:04.410360+00:00 app[web.1]: Log file: /app/log/passenger.11176.log
>   2018-05-22T14:22:04.410361+00:00 app[web.1]: Environment: production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You can use precompiled binary from oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com by upgrading your Ruby to the version they bundled for, e.g. to v2.2.8 if you use Passenger gem [v.5.3.1](https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.3.1/), or by downgrading the Passenger gem to [v5.1.9](https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.1.9/) if you prefer to stay with Ruby 2.2.7.

However [binaries are not critical](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phusion-passenger/5ulXXrxyIPE/J74aqzaoAwAJ) to Passenger operation. As the log says: `Passenger will still operate normally.` 
The absence of binaries Passenger tries to download [is also ok](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1950#issuecomment-306779766) - they don't publish binaries for every Ruby version. You can safely set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 and PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to mute both - that's in Config Vars settings of your Heroku app.

**Details re Passenger compilation issue:**
Passenger can't compile native binaries on Heroku, at least on new heroku-16 stack. We can inspect the /tmp/passenger_native_support-fgpk65.log and then mkmf.log by doing this:

```
heroku run bash 
bundle exec passenger start # just to make it fill the error log file
# hit [ctrl-c]
cat /tmp/passenger_native_support-*.log
```

Its output has smth like this:

```
# /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.3.4/src/ruby_native_extension/extconf.rb
checking for alloca.h... *** /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.3.4/src/ruby_native_extension/extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

It's not clear where's the mkmf.log file however, but we can make it appear in current dir by running `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.3.4/src/ruby_native_extension/extconf.rb` manually by using the same command that the log above has:

```
/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.3.4/src/ruby_native_extension/extconf.rb
cat mkmf.log
```

Then we have this:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.3.4/src/ruby_native_extension     -O3 -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-maybe-uninitialized  -fPIC -g conftest.c  -L. -L/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib -Wl,-R/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,'/../lib' -Wl,-R'/../lib' -lruby  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
sh: 1: gcc: not found
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

So, the root issue is that gcc is not available in heroku-16 stack runtime - and that's probably by purpose. It's not easy to make gcc available there, though it looks to be [possible](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-testrunner/issues/15#issuecomment-346595628), but I'd not go for that provided that we can solve this issue otherwise.